# Call a URL to perform an action using .NET

Tags: .net

I have a URL that I can call that will perform some tasks. I am writing a .NET console application that will call this URL but I am not sure how to do it. All I want is to pass a URL and wait until that URL has finished processing (the web page returns -1 when it has finished). I think it should be quite simple but am not sure where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I have just written some code using that and it worked but will mark this as the answer because it is :)